# A proof of no-cloning theorem in the case of pures states in a qubit system

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am working on this problem

Consider a qubit $\scr H =\Bbb C^2$  and pure states. Prove the no-clonning theorem
( hint: Use the linearity of the channel to arrive to a contradiction)

I wonder if the following proof of the non-cloning theorem for pure states I came up with is valid:

**My try:**

I have to prove that: **There is no quantum channel that clones all pure states**.

I am using the definitions written below.

A state $\rho$ is pure if there exist a unit vector $|\psi\rangle$ such that $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$. I can complete this vector to an orthonormal basis $B=\{|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle|\}$. So that

$\rho= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}$ with respect to this basis

and if by the sake of contradiction I assume that it can be cloned, there exists a quantum channel $\Phi$ such that
$\Phi(\rho)=\rho \otimes \rho =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Now I am supposed to use the lineary of the channel to arrive at a contradiction (that was a hint of the problem)but I think I can more easily observe that the trace is 2 and not 1 as it should, so it is not trace-preserving. A contradiction.

**Is this approach correct?** I am specially doubtful about the Hadamard product being correct despite the matrix is not using the standard basis and if the Hadamard product should have been be normalized at some point.

---

**Definition of quantum channel:**
A quantum chanel is a superoperator $\Phi$ (a map in $L(L(\scr {H_A}),L(\scr {H_B})$) that is trace preserving and  completely positive(  For all $\scr H_R$ and $M_{AR}\ge 0$, it holds that $(\Phi\otimes I_R)[M_{AR}]\ge 0$ )

**Definition of cloning:**

A quantum channel $\Phi \in C(\scr H,\scr H\otimes \scr H)$ (C is just the set of all quantum channels between the specified spaces)clones a state $\rho \in D(\scr H)$ if $\Phi[\rho]=\rho\otimes \rho$

Comment: This must be a Kronecker, and not a Hadamard product. The Kronecker product $\rho\otimes\rho$ is surely $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\,.$$

Comment: oops you are right I messed up the name and that entry. I guess this invalidates my proof, how would I fix it then?

Comment: I don't know. No-cloning theorems are nothing new. Perhaps you look up a standard reference.

Comment: @KurtG. Is the Kronecker product calculated the same if I use any orthogonal basis instead of the standard one? That is multiplying each entry of the first matrix by the whole second matrix and putting the results as blocks.

Comment: That's how a Kronecker product is defined. Look it up in Wikipedia. It has nothing to do with a basis.

Comment: I do not know much about this area but if I had to formulate it in terms of tensor products I would use the fact that the vector space of bilinear forms  has dimension $2 \times 2$ (four basis vectors $|0\rangle |0\rangle$, $|0\rangle |1\rangle$, $|1\rangle |0\rangle$, $|1\rangle |1\rangle$) and cloning generates only two basis vectors $|0\rangle |0\rangle$
and $|1\rangle |1\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to arrive at a contradiction using linearity, but a quite explicit one would be as follows:

> Assume there existed a channel $\Phi$ which satisfies
> $$\tag{1}
> \Phi(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\otimes|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
> $$
> for all unit vectors $\psi$.
> Starting from any two orthogonal unit vectors $\psi_1,\psi_2$ show that
>
> 1. $\langle \psi_1\otimes \psi_1\,|\,\Phi(|\psi_1\rangle\langle \psi_1|)\,|\,\psi_1\otimes \psi_1\rangle=1$ and $\langle \psi_1\otimes \psi_1\,|\,\Phi(|\psi_2\rangle\langle \psi_2|)\,|\,\psi_1\otimes \psi_1\rangle=0$ by applying (1).
> 2. both $\langle \psi_1\otimes \psi_1\,|\, \Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|) \,|\,\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\rangle$ and $\langle \psi_1\otimes \psi_1\,|\, \Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|) \,|\,\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\rangle$ are equal to $\frac14$, again, by applying${}^1$ (1).
> 3. because $\Phi$ is linear, it has to satisfy
>    $$
>    \Phi(|\psi_1\rangle\langle \psi_1|)+\Phi(|\psi_2\rangle\langle \psi_2|)=\Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|)+\Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|)$$

Doing so and combining these facts lets us arrive at the following contradiction:
\begin{align*}
1=1+0&=\langle\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\,|\,\Phi(|\psi_1\rangle\langle \psi_1|)+\Phi(|\psi_2\rangle\langle \psi_2|)\,|\,\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\rangle\\
&=\langle\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\,|\,\Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|)+\Phi(|\tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}\rangle\langle \tfrac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}|)\,|\,\psi_1\otimes\psi_1\rangle=\tfrac14+\tfrac14=\tfrac12
\end{align*}

---

<sub>${}^1$: Note that doing so is allowed because both $\frac{\psi_1+\psi_2}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{\sqrt2}$ are unit vectors as $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=0$ by assumption</sub>